# Why can't I install pandas-profiling on Cloud Datalab?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datalab, pandas-profiling

One of the main tools I like for initial data exploration:

Error message:

```
!pip install pandas-profiling
Downloading/unpacking pandas-profiling
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas- profiling (from versions: 1.0.0a1, 1.0.0a2, 1.0.0a1, 1.0.0a2)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for pandas-profiling
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `pandas-profiling` is in pre-release stage (Development Status - Alpha)  according to the following [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas-profiling).

Try the following solution:

1. Run the following command in a notebook to display the debug log mentioned in the error message:

   `!cat /root/.pip/pip.log`

   In the debug log, you should see the following note:

   `Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling-1.0.0a2.tar.gz#md5=ce6013c2600d6d0063ed773bf9e2a299 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pandas-profiling/), version 1.0.0a2 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow)`
2. Modify the install command to include the `--pre` option:

   `!pip install --pre pandas-profiling`

Answer (score 2):

Since I have received very few bug reports and the output is only used by humans anyway, I gave the current release (1.3.0) of pandas-profiling a 'stable' stage. That should solve your problem as well if the previous answer didn't.